# Cauchy Integral formula question

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> $$\int_{\gamma=(i,1)} \frac{z^3}{(z-i)^n} dz$$ for any  $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Can someone please help me answer this question as I cannot seem to get the right answer!

Please note that the Cauchy integral formula must be used in order to solve it.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your contour? It doesn't make sense currently.

Comment: well that is exactly how the question appears in the book.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: Maybe it means a circle of radius 1 centered at $i$?

Comment: yes it means |z| = 1 and centred at i. i dont know what a contour is, thats why im asking for help im massively stuck!!

Comment: A contour should have been introduced. Perhaps refer back to your notes from class.

Comment: r(cos t + i sin t) + w is that the contour?

Comment: A reasonable interpretation of the notation would suggest that the contour is $|z-i|=1$, traversed once counterclockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the residue theorem.
Since $\cfrac{z^3}{(z-i)^n}$ has a pole of order $n$ at $z=i$ and analytic everywhere other than $z=i$ in the domain $|z-i|<1$, by residue theorem, we have
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^3}{(z-i)^n}dz=2\pi ig(i),\text{where }g(z)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(z^3)^{(n-1)}$$

The residue theorem is obtained from Cauchy Integral formula.

By Cauchy Integral formula, we have 
$$2\pi if(z)=\int_C\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $z$ $n-1$ times, we get
$$2\pi if^{(n-1)}(z)=(n-1)!\int_C\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^n}d\zeta$$

Comment: I can't use the residue theorem is has to be the Cauchy Integral Formula!! Sorry but thank you :)

Comment: @camilla Residue theorem and Cauchy Integral Formula are actually the same thing. Or, just attach the "two-line proof" to your homework

Comment: is there not a way of putting it into partial fractions to solve? this is what im used to - not understanding very well sorry!! btw thank you for your answers.

Comment: Contour integral is different from the real one. You can not directly take the anti-derivative.

Comment: okay, im a bit confused about this one, but would the answer be (2pi)i?

Comment: It depends on what your $n$ is

Comment: its for any n in the natural numbers! Sorry im so confused as to how i apply this formula!! :/

Comment: Then, just write the general formula, $2\pi ig(i)$

Comment: $$(2\pi i)\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(z^3)^{(n-1)}$$)

Comment: ive got that as my answer, is it just left like this?

Comment: @camilla This integral depends on $n$, if it is a general $n$, that form is the best you can get.

Comment: okay thank you! this time it is for any n in natural numbers so I will leave it like that!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Parametrize the contour as $z=i+e^{i\theta}$ for $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$. Then, by definition, you have $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(e^{i\theta})^3}{((i+e^{i\theta})-i)^n}\cdot ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta=i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(e^{i\theta})^3}{e^{in\theta}}\cdot e^{i\theta}\,d\theta=i\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{i3\theta})e^{i(1-n)\theta}\,d\theta.$$Keep simplifying and you can solve it.

Comment: is that using the cauchy integral forumula though?? Many thanks

Comment: should i not put it into partial fractions and use the cauchy formula twice? I have a different looking answer here!